# How to change the decimal to 12 digit string

Tags: c#, string, format

How to change the double (currency) to 12 digit in c# toString();

For example

12.50 => 000000001250

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
string value = ((decimal)(12.50 * 100)).ToString().PadLeft(12, '0');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int a = (int)(12.50 * 100);
Console.WriteLine((a).ToString("D12"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
string formattedValue = value.ToString("000000000000");
```

value being the input and formattedValue as the output.